# How to handle didFocus - like React Native when navigate to or back from another screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

There is a way to know whether screen is hide (navigate to another screen) or resume (back from another screen) in React Native called didFocus hook. But I cannot find anything with the same function in Flutter.

Do you know any ways or ideas to implement this feature in Flutter? Thank you in advance.